# Python Web Scraping - How to scrape this type of site?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Okay, so I need to scrape the following webpage: https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?deadpool=1

It's a list of APIs. There are approx 22,000 APIs to scrape.

---

I need to:

1) Get the URL of each API in the table (pages 1-889), and also to scrape the following info:

- API name
- Description
- Category
- Submitted

2) I then need to scrape a bunch of information from each URL.

3) Export the data to a CSV

---

The thing is, I’m a bit lost of how to think about this project. From what I can see, there are no AJAX calls been made to populate the table, which means I’m going to have to parse the HTML directly (right?)

---

In my head, the logic would be something like this:

1. Use the requests & BS4 libraries to scrape the table
2. Then, somehow grab the HREF from every row
3. Access that HREF, scrape the data, move onto the next one
4. Rinse and repeat for all table rows.

---

Am I on the right track, is this possible with requests & BS4?

Here's are some [screenshots](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fVWTWeHKcOkRROhcn-9v8_QQzZT4ZN_1zavtYXgmdLA/edit?usp=sharing) of what I've been trying to explain.

Thank you SOO much for any help. This is hurting my head haha

Comment: What have you tried so far !

Comment: What is the question you're asking? If you're just asking if this is possible with BS4 and Requests, the answer is (most likely) yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go using `requests`, `BeautifulSoup` and `pandas`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?deadpool=1&page='

num = int(input('How Many Page to Parse?> '))
print('please wait....')
name = []
desc = []
cat = []
sub = []
for i in range(0, num):
    r = requests.get(f"{url}{i}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for item1 in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'views-field views-field-title col-md-3'}):
        name.append(item1.text)
    for item2 in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'views-field views-field-search-api-excerpt views-field-field-api-description hidden-xs visible-md visible-sm col-md-8'}):
        desc.append(item2.text)
    for item3 in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'views-field views-field-field-article-primary-category'}):
        cat.append(item3.text)
    for item4 in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'views-field views-field-created'}):
        sub.append(item4.text)

result = []
for item in zip(name, desc, cat, sub):
    result.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    result, columns=['API Name', 'Description', 'Category', 'Submitted'])
df.to_csv('output.csv')

print('Task Completed, Result saved to output.csv file.')
```

Result can be viewed online: [Check Here](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=886bbe3d1c94a844b456f19ed051845db227f822eb0dd237fe8fa6a7529ed5707f42235af0d7c9e303b85a8def35465bd922dd454afc384e26085db3d391d38c)

Output Simple:

[image]

Now For `href` parsing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?deadpool=0&page='

num = int(input('How Many Page to Parse?> '))
print('please wait....')

links = []
for i in range(0, num):
    r = requests.get(f"{url}{i}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'views-field views-field-title col-md-3'}):
        for href in link.findAll('a'):
            result = 'https://www.programmableweb.com'+href.get('href')
            links.append(result)

spans = []
for link in links:
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    span = [span.text for span in soup.select('div.field span')]
    spans.append(span)

data = []
for item in spans:
    data.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
print('Task Completed, Result saved to data.csv file.')
```

Check Result Online: [Here](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=8059035d83f7549efc8d1e42de7adb3b50c56978993e7379e34d6137213248a05ad614759e69f95eabd37cf3be45dcacd5eec2e45c58ce6fa96e73acf48e76c6)

Sample View is Below:

[image]

In Case if you want those 2 `csv` files together so here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("output.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
merged = a.merge(b)
merged.to_csv("final.csv", index=False)
```

Online Result: [Here](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/editor.do?doc=041e1cfa23ee5a62418b155925380d179f1934cbc78c3c9cfe8a089da65dec3175b8cad03a09cc8d5b330dcea65895657872c513b23346264b15bafff42004ba)

Comment: Wow! This is a big help man, I've been studying the code for close to an hour and I'll be using it as a reference from now on. Thank you so much!

I have a question, using panda - is it possible to extract the non-table elements.  More specially, the part of the page that shows the numbers for 'SDKs', 'Articles', 'How to' etc.  

It's a <ul> with class="nav nav-tabs menu hidden-xs listprofile-display-count-style".

Comment: @Luke Aha i got your question, for example `https://www.programmableweb.com/api/google-maps` so you want to extract `SDKS` ?

Comment: @Luke you can do it via `beautifulsoup` indeed. `pandas` is easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools for the Python programming language. read about it https://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: Absolutely! You've helped me a lot! And yes, the SDKs, along with the other information in that section.  Would it be possible to write all of the above data to the same CSV file?

Comment: @Luke you referring to `output.csv` and `data.csv` ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I've also just been able to locate the extra data I needed thanks to your help (the SKDs etc).  So now I'm able to output the 2 files (output.csv and data.csv).  Would it be possible to 'merge' the two files, so that 'A2' contains the data from both the A2s of 'output.csv and data.csv?  YOu have no idea how much you're saving my life with this. I would buy you a beer if I could!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202790/discussion-between--c-and-luke).

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about **scraping** if you are going to pursue it .

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv , os , requests
from urllib import parse


def SaveAsCsv(list_of_rows):
    try:
        with open('data.csv', mode='a',  newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            csv.writer(outfile).writerow(list_of_rows)
    except PermissionError:
        print("Please make sure data.csv is closed\n")

if os.path.isfile('data.csv') and os.access('data.csv', os.R_OK):
    print("File data.csv Already exists \n")
else:
    SaveAsCsv([ 'api_name','api_link','api_desc','api_cat'])
BaseUrl = 'https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?deadpool=1&page={}'
for i in range(1, 890):
    print('## Getting Page {} out of 889'.format(i))    
    url = BaseUrl.format(i)
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
    table_rows = soup.select('div.view-content > table[class="views-table cols-4 table"] > tbody tr')
    for row in table_rows:
        tds = row.select('td')
        api_name = tds[0].text.strip()
        api_link = parse.urljoin(url, tds[0].find('a').get('href'))
        api_desc = tds[1].text.strip()
        api_cat  = tds[2].text.strip()  if len(tds) >= 3 else ''
        SaveAsCsv([api_name,api_link,api_desc,api_cat])
```

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I do scraping on daily basis So just adjusted it a bit . Vote it up for being lucky though .